# Unable to align ImageView to bottom of RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I've read several tutorials on how to do this, but for whatever reason, my image won't budge from the center of the screen.  The ninjas image is 1080x517px

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:weightSum="1"
              android:background="@color/white">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ninjas"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ninjas"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

From what I can tell, this is correct.  Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You make the image fill the parent currently. Change

```
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

to

```
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ninjas"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ninjas"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ninjas"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

to

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ninjas"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ninjas"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

At present your `ImageView` is occupying all the space in its parent. After changing `layout_width` and `layout_height` to `wrap_content` it will only occupy as much space as size of `@drawable/ninjas`

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this, however it doesn't seem to change.  The default image size is 1080x517px, however I am testing on an N5.  I'm not sure if the image size is interfering with the layout as if I use the app icon, it sits in the correct position..

Comment: Then its the image size's issue

Comment: N5 is 1080px wide and so is the image.  Surely the point is that the image scales to the width of the ImageView and keeps the ratio, therefore it shouldn't matter on the size of the image...

Comment: Your problem was that you were not able to align it to the bottom of your `RelativeLayout` but you said if you use an icon you are able to do so.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem...

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="bottom|right"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ninjas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ninjas"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

</LinearLayout
```